# how to write gtest for code containing constructor and having dependancy

Tags: c++, constructor, googletest, googlemock

I have one c++ code, for that i need to write `gtest`.
I am trying to write from so many days by using different suggestions but not yet fully able to write and understand as i'm beginner to `gtest`.

it will be helpful if i get `gtest` code for my `.h` class

here is my `RTIParticipant.h` code

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class DDSDomainParticipant;
class RTIParticipant
{
        public:
                DDSDomainParticipant* getDDSParticipant();
                int getDomainID();
                ~RTIParticipant();
                RTIParticipant(string name="", int domainID=0, string qosLibName="", string qosProfileName="");
        private:
                string _name;
                int _domainID;
                DDSDomainParticipant* _ddsDomainParticipant;
};
```

Comment: afaik there is no one fits all recipe for how to write tests. To write a test one needs to know what a class is supposed to be used for, but with the header alone it can be difficult to write a meaningful test

Comment: It's unclear from the question what you are trying to test and what problem you are having.  Please include more information.